# How to prevent IE10 from crashing when it tries to use the DomObject.filters property?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have some old JavaScript code that I **can't** change crashing on IE10 (I can change other script files).

Here is the crashing code:

```
if(isInternetExplorer && this.domElement.filters[0])
  this.domElement.filters[0].play()
```

That code will not crash in ie8/9 because the DOM element has the non standard property "filters".

Here is the documentation to the [filters property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The only solution I can think of is to change the HtmlElement's prototype but I don't feel like it is actually possible or the good thing to do.

So how can I prevent IE10 from crashing when it tries to use the DomObject.filters property?

[EDIT]
I just found a 'solution'. This is also [@JAM's solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16552430/613568):

```
if (!HTMLDivElement.filters) {
    HTMLDivElement.prototype.filters = [];
}
```

But I still feel bad about modifying a browser native object's prototype.

Comment: What's `isInternetExplorer`, can you override it?

Comment: No I can't override it.

Comment: When you say "crashing" -- is it really crashing the browser? Got a repro page?

Comment: The script crashes. I'll make a jsfiddle.

Comment: This is that simple: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTGry/ . Go in IE to find out. It will crash on IE10 but not <IE10

Comment: I don't know what "The script crashes" means. Do you mean that it throws an exception because you're trying to touch a property that doesn't exist? If so, you should update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, overriding the prototype of the object is one way of doing it; ***so if there is no other alternative*** you could try this:

`Object.prototype.filters = Object.prototype.filters || []`

Or even better (as you suggested your self):

`HTMLDivElement.prototype.filters = HTMLDivElement.prototype.filters || []`

This will set the filters property of the object, if it is non-existing.

Comment: I edited my question, it is not necessary to have a default object with the play function. See my edit.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc let me know if this solved your problem :)

Comment: It actually solves the problem. I will still wait for some more answers in case there is an other magical solution of something like that.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc Great :)

Comment: -1 as modifying `Object.prototype` like this breaks every `for in`-enumeration!

Comment: @Bergi I am well aware of that, and as I said "if there is no other alternative you could try this". But I will emphasize it in the answer :)

Comment: I actually use HTMLDivElement.prototype.filters and it does not seem to break anything.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc Even better!

Answer (score 1):

Umm, use feature detection instead of browser detection? No `isInternetExplorer` please, but `doesSupportFilters`:

```
var el = this.domElement;
if (el.filters && el.filters.length && typeof el.filters[0].play == "function")
    el.filters[0].play();
```

Comment: Quote from the question: "I have some old JavaScript code that I **can't** change..."